# Robot Framework:How to access a global variable from __init__ file

Tags: robotframework

I have a __init__.csv file under Suit folder, and int this __init__.csv file I try to access a global variable which is defined in a resource file, but it reports "FAIL : Variable '${WORKSPACE_BASE_DIR}' not found".
Here's my code in __init__.csv

```
*Settings*                          
Suite Setup Setup Test Environment                      
Suite Teardown  Cleanup Test Environment                                            
Resource    ../Resource/variables.tsv                       
Library SSHLibrary                      

*Keywords*                          
Setup Test Environment  ${path}=    Join Path   ${WORKSPACE_BASE_DIR}   ssh.log         
Enable SSH Logging  ${path}                 


Cleanup Test Environment    Close All Connections
```

Code in variables.tsv

```
*Settings*                          

*Variables*                         
${ENVNAME}  Windows                     

*Keywords*                          
Linux   Set Global Variable ${WORKSPACE_BASE_DIR}   a linux path                

Windows Set Global Variable ${WORKSPACE_BASE_DIR}   a windows path
```

Can someone tell me where goes wrong?

Comment: *Keywords* and *Variables* defined/imported in the `__init__.robot` will not be available in the test suites. [Robot Framework User guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#initialization-files)

Comment: But inside the \__init__.robot, can I use a global variable that is defined in another file?  I know user guide says "Variables and keywords created or imported in initialization filesare not available in the lower level test suite". But I am not trying to use the variable in the lower level test suite, I am trying to use the variable in this \__init__.robot, is that possible in Robot Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you provided, you only set that variable if you call the `Linux` or `Windows` keyword. You're not calling either of those keywords anywhere.